# Shipping per Product (in cart)?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I am looking for an extension that enables the buyer to choose from a variety of shipment options in the cart. So one product in the cart should get basic shipping of $5 for example. Another one should have premium shipping which costs $15 and yet another one should have special shipping which costs $50.

So in case of 2 items in the cart and one has basic and one special shipping, the costs for shipping should be $55.

The shipping types should be configurable in the admin and of course the ones above are just examples. I googled a bit and found some "shipment per product" extension, but none of them does what I described above.

Any idea if such an extension exists?

**Magento 2**

Thanks!